# PostgreSQL full text search - prioritizing results for results matching with all terms

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, ranking

Hi I'd like to define a query for PostgreSQL full-text search such that the results matching with all the terms are ranked higher while results matching with only some of the terms are also retrieved.

Example:

query: `tree wood`

I'd like to get results including both words in higher ranks. However, I'd also like to get results including only `tree` or `wood`.

I tried to use `plainto_tsquery ('tree | wood')` but this does not prioritize the records including all query terms.

I have a database column typed `ts_vector` and I'm doing the search on this column.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

**Solution**: I was able to achieve what I want after sorting the results by rank explicitly with something like:

```
select * from table, to_tsquery('english', 'wood | tree') query where vector_column @@ query order by ts_rank_cd(search_index, query) desc;
```

Comment: Run two queries: one with `'tree & wood'` and one with `'tree | wood'`. Display the results from the first query with higher rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in ranking functions `ts_rank` and `ts_rank_cd` should do this automatically.  Note that the query fed to the ranking functions should be the one with the `|`, not `&`.

Note that it will probably be faster to first do the `&` query, and then do the `|` query only if the first one found no rows.  But of course then you don't get any `|` rows if there is at least one `&` row, so you have to decide whether that is acceptable.